# Website password does not work on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, passwords

I've protected my website using a password (I don't really need a "real" protection, it's just a small save the date website, no big deal, just don't want people to mind my business ;) )

But the code I've used does not seem to work on mobile version. Whenever I enter the password I chose, I always get the error message of wrong password, even if it's correct. Any idea of how can I possibly solve this?

```
var password = "please";
var x = prompt("Enter in the password "," ");
if (x.toLowerCase() == password) {
  alert("Come right in \n \n You've entered in the right password");
  window.location = "index.htm";
}
else {
  window.location = "bad.htm";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at your line:

```
var x = prompt("Enter in the password "," ");
```

Your second parameter is adding a blank space before your answer " ". You should use the blank parameter "".

For example if you type your password: please. Instead of comparing "please" to "please" it will wrongly compare "please" to " please".

Comment: This could be the issue, but only if the OP is adding to the default text instead of replacing it. And, it wouldn't explain why it's working on desktop, but not mobile.  In addition to your advice, all user input should also get the `.trim()` string function applied to it, to remove any leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: When `prompt` is opened on desktop, it shows the space selected, so when a user types a password, the space is overwritten. Mobile browser do the same, but when you click on a field to focus it and to show the onscreen keyboard, the selection disappears and space in the beginning of the prompt input. Try it - https://jsfiddle.net/5s9dyLmt/1/

Comment: It worked! I erased the blank space within the "" and now it works on both mobile and desktop. Thank you!